ROS navigation map and pose
I'm trying to do navigation in ROS, but when I run navigation, the data drawn by lidar scan is not erased and remains and gets lumped together. Also, if you try to specify the initial coordinates with a 2d pose estimate, it works fine the first time, but from the next time, the coordinates are set to a completely wrong place. Does anyone know the cause and solution?



I am pretty sure that there is a setting in Rviz that controls then amount of time on the screen.
